# How to change variables $\tilde{x} = \frac{x-1}{x+1}$ in a differential equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, change-of-variable

I'm told that the Legendre equation

$$(1-x^2)\frac{d^2P_n}{dx^2}-2x\frac{dP_n}{dx} +n(n+1)P_n=0$$

can be transformed by a change of variables $\tilde{x}=\frac{1-x}{1+x}$ into the hypergeometric equation.  So to try to perform that change of variables I write

$$\tilde{x}+x\tilde{x}=1-x \qquad \Rightarrow \qquad x(\tilde{x}+1)=1-\tilde{x} \qquad \Rightarrow $$
$$x=\frac{1-\tilde{x}}{1+\tilde{x}}$$

Next I want to know the relationship between derivatives, so

$$\frac{dx}{dx} = \frac{-\frac{d\tilde{x}}{dx}(1+\tilde{x})-(1-\tilde{x})\frac{d\tilde{x}}{dx}}{(1+\tilde{x})^2} \qquad \Rightarrow $$
$$1=\frac{-2\frac{d\tilde{x}}{dx}}{(1+\tilde x)^2}$$

So $\frac{d\tilde x}{dx} = -(1+\tilde x)^2/2$.

So now we can write $P_n(x) = y(\tilde x)$ and

$$\frac{dP_n}{dx} = \frac{d}{dx}y(\tilde x) = y'(\tilde x)\cdot -(1+\tilde x)^2/2$$

$$\frac{d^2P_n}{dx^2} = -\frac{1}{2}\left( 2(1+\tilde x)\frac{d\tilde x}{dx}y'(\tilde x) + (1+\tilde x)^2y''\frac{d\tilde x}{dx} \right)$$
$$=\frac{(1+\tilde x)^3}{4}\left(2y'+(1+\tilde x)y''\right)$$

After substituting these into the Legendre equation, though, doesn't seem to transform it into anything nice or useful.  It's making me wonder if I've done something wrong.

Comment: You have done a mistake $$\tilde{x}+x \tilde{x}=x-1 \quad \text{not} \quad1-x.$$ Better to cross check before posting.

Comment: @ManojKumar Is this not going from $\tilde x = \frac{1-x}{1+x}$ to $(1+x)\tilde x = 1-x$ and from here $\tilde x + x \tilde x = 1-x$?  Perhaps I'm not seeing what you're referring to.

Comment: @Addam But in title of your question transformation is different. May be it is just typo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is that you have to set
$$
P_n(x) = \frac{y(\tilde{x})}{(1-\tilde{x})^n}.
$$
Do this and it should all work out.

Alternatively you could set $\tilde{x} = (1-x)/2$, which also gives the hypergeometric equation and is algebraically simpler. The form for $\tilde{x} = (x-1)/(x+1)$ then follows from the [Pfaff transformation](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/PfaffTransformation.html).

Comment: Is this the same as setting $\tilde x = \frac{1-x}{1+x}$ and I'm not understanding how this is the same?  Or are you saying that the transformation given is not correct, and to use your different transformation instead?

Comment: @Addem First, the transformation is $\tilde{x} = (x-1)/(x+1)$. You have it right in the title but not the body of the question. So you'll need to redo the work of finding $d\tilde{x}/dx$. Second, you need to set $y(\tilde{x}) = (1-\tilde{x})^n P_n(x)$ or else the resulting equation isn't the hypergeometric equation. Which means you'll also have to redo the calculations for $y'(\tilde{x})$ and $y''(\tilde{x})$. But it does all work out.